# Prior Week Sales as per slicer selection in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a slicer selection to be used to get selected week data and the last week data. I am unable to get prior week sales information.

Here is the relationship between the tables.
[image]

Here are the DAX codes I used:

```
selected week =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( Sales[Sales] ), ALLSELECTED ( CalendarWeek[Week and Date] ) )


Prior Week =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sales[Sales] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( CalendarWeek[Week and Date] ),
        DATEADD ( 'Date'[Date], -7, DAY )
    )
```

here is a snapshot of the visuals in power BI.
[image]

Could anyone please have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: is your Week and Date a 'Date' field or a 'Text' field?

Comment: what fields are 'CalendarWeek' and 'Date' joined on?

Comment: @Aldert Its a text field. I am using Direct Query and have created this column as required by concatenating week number and week ending date.

Comment: @StelioK The calendarweek table has weekly dates, the two tables join with calendarweek.weekendingdate = date.date

Comment: What is then the relation to the Date[Date] and the CalendarWeek[???] @StelioK is asking the same

Comment: The calendarweek table as weekendingdate column, which is a date column but only consists of weekend dates. It is related to date table with date[date] by calendarweek[weekendingdate].

Comment: so 'Date'[Date] is a text field with weekend dates?

Comment: if you'd like to take advantage of the built in DAX Time Intelligence functions you will need to reference a contiguous date type field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated your scenario and it works perfecty fine. Only when I select the first week, I get a blank from the previous week what is correct because there is no data.

Model:
[image]

**result**:

[image]

If you want to have a zero instead of blank, you can use:

```
Prior Week = 
    var totalSales = CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sales[Sales] );
        ALLSELECTED ( CalendarWeek[CalendarWeekKey] );
        DATEADD ( 'Date'[Date]; -7; DAY )
    )
return if (totalSales = BLANK();0;totalSales)
```

Comment: Hey Aldert, I removed and recreated the relationships and it worked. My code is the same as your code, not sure why it would not work before. Thank you for your input on the 0 instead of the blank result as well.